# Buildbot run step on master?

Tags: git, buildbot

I have a buildbot setup with a slave that has no access to the internet. This causes problems during checkout:

```
slave = BuildFactory()
slave.addStep(Git(repourl=..., mode='full'))
```

The master change source polls git (it has outside access), kicks off the slave which tries to checkout the source and fails.

Can I run a single buildstep on the master? I see I can run a shell command with MasterShellCommand:

```
slave.addStep(MasterShellCommand(command="I'm run on master!"))
```

But what I really want is the whole step:

```
slave.addStep(MasterShellCommand(step=Git(repourl=...)))
```

Or do I have implement this all myself?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement anything more complicated that a shell command yourself. The [buildbot.steps.master class](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.2/reference/buildbot.steps.master-pysrc.html) isn't very complicated.

That being said, slave-side source checkout steps were removed in Buildbot-0.9.0 If you're using an older version of buildbot, the two different types of source checkout are [documented](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.10/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#module-buildbot.steps.source).